# Displaying dates in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new with this field. However, I'm having a trouble displaying the dates on my table. Can someone help me on how can I display the date today on the first row and the first day of the following months on the next rows?

```
function load_assessment() {

  let formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US');
  var tf_amount=parseFloat($("#tf_amount_hide").val());
  var amount_percent=parseFloat($("#amount_percent").val());
  var mf_amount=parseFloat($("#mf_amount").val())
  var cal_tf_amount = tf_amount - amount_percent;

  $("#tf_amount").val(cal_tf_amount);
  $("#mf_amount").val(mf_amount);
  var tot_assessed = cal_tf_amount + mf_amount;
  $("#tot_assessed").val(tot_assessed);

  var today = new Date();
  var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;

  var no_pay=parseFloat($("#no_pay").val());
  var quo_total = tot_assessed / no_pay;

  if(no_pay > 0) {

     for($i = 1; $i <= no_pay; $i++) {

       if ($i == 1) {
       $('#payment_plan_tab').append('\
         <tr>\
         <td>\PAYMENT '+$i+' (D/P)</td>\
         <td>'+today+'</td>\
         <td>'+quo_total+'</td>\
         </tr>');
       } else {
         $('#payment_plan_tab').append('\
           <tr>\
           <td>\PAYMENT '+$i+'</td>\
           <td>'+nextMonth+'</td>\
           <td>'+quo_total+'</td>\
           </tr>');
       }
     }
  }
}
```

The picture below is the sample of the table that I'm currently doing. The AMOUNT column is where I used the `tot_assessed` and `no_pay`.
[image: SAMPLE]

Comment: How/where are `tot_assessed` and `no_pay` used? ... looks like `no_pay` is at least from some input.

Comment: Can you update your post with the code for `tot_assessed`

Comment: @PaulT. there is an AMOUNT column in my table so that where I used it.

Comment: @Reed I already updated the question with the whole function that I'm currently using.

Comment: @PaulT. `no_pay` determines how many rows of the table must be shown and on how many months should the user pay.